# Multiclass Classification for Multiple Minority Classes

Tags: classification, feature-selection, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance

I've been working on a multiclass problem (5 classes) and having some challenges on Feature Selection and Class Imbalance.

I have around 1,000 rows and 2,000 features (which I also generated exhaustively) consisting of in-app activity (data has many zeros because of inactive users, making the distribution right skewed with long tail).

The target variable is distributed like this:

Class 0: 2% 
Class 1: 5% 
Class 2: 10% 
Class 3: 30% 
Class 4: 55%

Please critic my workflow below and feel free to suggest steps that can improve my solution.

1. Split the data into Train-Test and Holdout Sets.
2. Check the skewness of each feature and if > 0.5, use Square Root transformation.
3. After the transformation, ~95% of the features are still skewed, therefore use RobustScaler() instead of StandardScaler().
4. Drop Constant and Quasi-constant features.
5. Create different training sets using the following Feature Selection techniques:

   a. Filter Method: SelectKBest - Since my features are continuous, use ANOVA (Find k using Cross Validation).

   b. Wrapper Method: Recursive Feature Elimination - Use Random Forest as an estimator (Using RFECV)

   c. Embedded Methods: LASSOCV(Weird, because it retained only 1 feature out of 2,000), RidgeCV (Arbitrarily pick the top 5% features) and Random Forest Feature Importance (top 5% features).
6. Create more training sets but this time, check for multicollinearity using Variance Inflation Factor and Correlation.
7. Train the following models on all of the training sets generated from the different Feature Selection techniques (someone tell me if this is the right thing to do):

   a. LASSO Regression 
   b. Ridge Regression 
   c. SVM 
   d. Decision Tree 
   e. Random Forest 
   f. XGBoost 
   g. LightGBM 
   h. CatBoost
8. Evaluate and compare results using classification metrics and review the confusion matrix (a complete diagonal, the better).

**Results:** Most of the models scored at only around 20-25% Balanced Accuracy and Macro F1-Score, maybe because of the class imbalance.

I've read some Q&As here that the best thing to do is to "do nothing" for these type of cases since SMOTE/oversampling/undersampling changes the sample and destroys the calibration.

Will built in Class Weights parameter help me (does this also change the calibration) or is this a case of adjusting the threshold based on business decisions?

Sorry for the long post, I'm just wondering why I cannot get higher scores than 25%.

Thank you.

Comment: [Asked and answered on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/642693/247274).